# Accessing object for every agent in JADE

Tags: java, agents-jade

I have some object, e.g.

`MyData data;`

How can I make it distributed, so every agent can access and change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use the same JVM, you can just create singleton (dont forget about synchronization) otherwise you can create an agent that will have a link on your common object and change it with messages (ACLMessages requests) like a web service.

Comment: Even though that both suggestions work programmatically, only one is correct. As JADE serves the Agent Oriented design, an appropriate design is to have singletons ONLY for getting final data at the same JVM. In order to modify data in a distributed fashion, only the second option you have provided is valid by an agent oriented perspective.